# Some problem with the font of my laptop in Fedora 14

Tags: linux, fedora

I am not sure what changes I had made. I installed the KDE environment and gnome-shell last night. Till 1 hour back the font was smooth and looking good. All of a sudden I don't remmeber what changes I had made but the font is not smooth. But when I go to the font settings they are set to the same values as before.
[image: Screenshot of the font]

Can someone help me with this. The words are not clear and legible.

Answer (score 2):

Turn subpixel smoothing (assuming you're using an LCD screen) back on.

Comment: It is on. I didnt change anything,